# get_post_meta not working on my custom-function page

Tags: metabox, post-meta

I have saved the meta key with the name `writer_meta_key` and want to retrieve it on my custom-functions page. I can get it on front page and single page but it doesn't work on my custom-function page. Here is my code. It gives only title but not the writer's name.

```
$term       = get_queried_object();
$tax_object = get_taxonomy( $term->taxonomy );
$post_type_array = $tax_object->object_type;
$post_type  = $post_type_array[0];

$posts      = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => $post_type,
    'taxonomy'  => $term->taxonomy,
    'term'      => $term->slug
) );

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $custom_meta_writer = get_post_meta( $id, 'writer_meta_key', true );       
    $writer = $custom_meta_writer['writer'];
    echo $post->post_title; 
    echo $writer; 
}
```

When I echo `$id` it shows error as

```
Array
Array
Array
Array
```

Where have I mistaken??

Comment: Welcome to WPSE.  Where is your custom-function page used?  Is it an include file called by a page template?

Comment: It's included in a folder inc and is called in functions.php

Comment: It is important to remember that WordPress is an application that runs when a user requests content and does nothing otherwise (over-simplified) so my question is related to that. What triggers the code above to actually run?  Typically custom functions (or plugins) are fired when the action they are hooked to is called.

Comment: First of all I'ven't used any plugins in this project. This is just a page where I've done all the codings. The above code displays the category posts and what I need is to retrive the meta key of the title.

Comment: To simplify the question - how does this code get called?  It isn't in a function hooked to an action.  It is not part of a page template.  How would WordPress know this code exists?

Comment: It's called in a function `function render_custom($term)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress uses a `global $post` to keep track of the current post the user is viewing. Whenever you call functions like `the_title()` or [`get_the_ID()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) it uses that `global $post` to pull that data. In your code snippet you're using `get_posts()` which generally does not overwrite the `global $post` object unless you specify with `setup_postdata( $post )`.

The easiest thing to do is to simply modify your metadata line and use:

```
$custom_meta_writer = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'writer_meta_key', true );
```

Comment: I used `setup_postdata( $post );` after foreach loop and it worked. Thanks. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Jklyn By using `setup_postdata( $post )` you're overwriting the `global $post` object. Make sure you reset it by calling [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/) after your loop.